# Does ReasonML have an equivalent of F#'s Computation Expressions?

Tags: monads, reason, computation-expression

In F# we have [Computation Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions), which can reduce boiler-plate and nesting when working in various computational contexts (async, optionals and so on).

- Does ReasonML have an equivalent of this?
- If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, nope; no computation expressions. Reason is just another syntax still sharing all of the OCaml semantics, so a similar behavior is commonly achieved using modules, functors and composition.

**However**, Reason and OCaml have *ppx rewriters*, that allow extending the syntax to achieve this sort of things. There is already an [open issue about a special syntax for asynchronous and awaitable computations](https://github.com/facebook/reason/issues/1321).

Some useful *ppx rewriters* that are similar to computation expressions:

- [ppx_let](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_let): Monadic let-bindings
- [ppx_lwt](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/dev/api/Ppx_lwt): LWT programming, async/await
- [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving): Haskell like type deriving, like for `Show`, `Eq`and `Ord`